# rewriting _.memoize in underscore library

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I am practicing rewriting _.memoize in underscore library and having some difficulties getting it right. I would like to make it so it would return a function that will check if it has already computed the result for the given argument and return that stored value for a call with the same argument.

can someone give some advice on this to make it properly working?

```
  _.memoize = function(func) {
    var cache = {}, result;
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    return function(){
      if(args in cache) {
        return cache[arg];
      } else {
        return cache[arg] = func.apply(this, arguments)
      };
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

You have spelling mistake, `arg` should be `args`.

```
  _.memoize = function(func) {
    var cache = {}, result;
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    return function(){
      if(args in cache) {
        return cache[args];
      } else {
        return cache[args] = func.apply(this, arguments)
      };
    }
  };
```